# Eager loading of related model (nested set)

Tags: activerecord, yii2

In Yii1 I could load parent (nested set) using eager loading. It was like this:

```
class Category extends CActiveRecord {
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'parent' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Category', '', 'on' => '(t.left between    parent.left and parent.right) and parent.level + 1 = t.level', 'joinType'=>'left join'),
        );
    }
}
```

(relation to the same model, setting 2nd parameter as empty, and setting my own condition in `on` parameter).

How can I do the same in Yii2? (cause Yii2 needs `key => value` pair to initialize relation).

Answer (score 0):

Try use like this:

```
public function getRelation()
{
     return $this->hasOne(RelationTable::className(), ['id' => 'relation_id'])->onCondition(array|string)->andOnCondition(array|string);
}
```

or

```
public function getRelation()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(RelationTable::className(), ['id' => 'relation_id'])->andOnCondition(array|string);
    }
```

More is here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data